# Archiving Scanned Family Photos, How to Annotate?

Tags: photos, metadata

I'm scanning old family photos for saving and distribution to family. I'd like to be able to give all known info about the photo. iPhoto would work, but most people don't have Macs. For cross platform, I consider naming the pictures and including a text file with info about all photos. Seems like this could be upgraded easily as formats change, but doesn't store annotations with photos. Any ideas?

Comment: JPEG photos can store IPTC metadata, including tags, dates and comments; these can be read and modified by many photo viewer/manager programs.

Answer (score 2):

[irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/)  Download and install the version with all plug-ins.You will like it, I'm sure.